# how to remove forward slash using javascript

Tags: javascript

how to remove forword slash in javascript?

i am using .replace(///g, '') but not woking.

var testtext = '{\"AnonymousTraveler\": { \"PTC\": \"ADT\" }}';

console.log(testtext);

Comment: there's no forward slash in your input

Comment: your code outputs {"AnonymousTraveler": { "PTC": "ADT" }} to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Front slashes need to be escaped:

```
/\//g
```

Comment: i am using in replace method '/\//g ' but not working

Comment: But like people said above, where is the front slash in your input? I only left this answer here in case you had mistyped your code!

Comment: using this code /\\/g working fine. thank you all

Comment: Then please accept the answer, and have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var testtext = '{\"AnonymousTraveler\": { \"PTC\": \"ADT\" }}';
testtext = testtext.replace("\\","");
alert(testtext);
```

Comment: using this code /\\/g working fine. thank you all